# spring boot Javax validation on nested DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a DTO class (`treeDTO`) that contains within it two other DTO classes (`DistributionDTO` and `BlossomDTO`).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.Set;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class TreeDTO {

    @NotBlank(message = "Family cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("family")
    private String family;

    @NotBlank(message = "Genius cannot be empty.")
    @JsonProperty("genius")
    private String genius;

    @NotBlank(message = "Species cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("species")
    private String species;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Common name(s) cannot be empty.")
    @JsonProperty("common_name")
    private Set<String> commonNames;

    @NotNull(message = "Distribution cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("distribution")
    @Valid
    private DistributionDTO distributionDTO;

    @NotNull(message = "Blossom cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("blossom")
    @Valid
    private BlossomDTO blossomDTO;
}
```

and

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class DistributionDTO {

    @NotNull(message = "Neophyte cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("neophyte")
    private Boolean isNeophyte;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Areal cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("areal")
    private Set<arealEnum> areal;

}
```

and

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class BlossomDTO {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Blossom color cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("color")
    private Set<BlossomColorEnum> blossomColor;

    @NotNull(message = "Odor cannot be empty.")
    //@NotNull(message = "Blossom odor cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("odor")
    private Boolean isBlossomOdor;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Blossom period cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("period")
    private Set<BlossomPeriodEnum> blossomPeriod;

    @NotNull(message = "Blossom ornamental cannot be null.")
    @JsonProperty("ornamental")
    private Boolean isBlossomOrnamental;

}
```

Everything is handled by a controller that receives as input a JSON:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="api/v1/tree-finder")
public class TreeController {

    private final TreeService treeService;

    @Autowired
    public TreeController(TreeService treeService) {
        this.treeService = treeService;
    }

    @PostMapping(
            value = "/create-tree",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> createTree(

            @RequestBody
            @Valid
            TreeDTO treeDTO,
            BindingResult result
    ){
        System.out.println(treeDTO.getFamily());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

what I'm trying to do is handle the following cases that if incorrect should generate an error:

**correct case**

```
{
    "family": "test1",
    "genius": "tes2",
    "species": "test3",
    "common_name": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ],
    "distribution": {
        "neophyte": true,
        "areal": ["015"]
    },
    "blossom":{
        "color": ["brown"],
        "odor": true,
        "period": [1, 2, 3],
        "ornamental": true
    }
}
```

[image]

**first error case**: in this case if it is missing in the JSON `distributionDTO` and/or `blossomDTO` should raise an error (in the example below distributionDTO is missing)

```
{
    "family": "test1",
    "genius": "tes2",
    "species": "test3",
    "common_name": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ],
    "blossom":{
        "color": ["brown"],
        "odor": true,
        "period": [1, 2, 3],
        "ornamental": true
    }
}
```

[image]

**second error case**: in this case the DTO classes (`distributionDTO` and `blossomDTO`) may be present but a variable is missing (in the example `Boolean isNeophyte` of `DistributionDTO` is missing):

```
{
    "family": "test1",
    "genius": "tes2",
    "species": "test3",
    "common_name": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ],
    "distribution": {
        "areal": ["015"]
    },
    "blossom":{
        "color": ["brown"],
        "odor": true,
        "period": [1, 2, 3],
        "ornamental": true
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add `spring-boot-starter-validation` or only `validation-api`? I suspect the latter, if so replace `validation-api` with `spring-boot-starter-validation`. If not add your dependencies to the question.

Comment: yes. Updated the question

Comment: Also your controller is always returning `OK`, you have included the `BindingResult` so it will never throw an error, unless you do that yourself in the controller. You need to check if there is an error, if so return 400 else return 200, or remove the `BindingResult` from the method.

Comment: Pleae don't add code as screenshots but as code. THe screenshot is unreadable (that being said, remove the `version` you shouldn't have `version` in `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. I removed BindingResult and now I have the error. Now I have a doubt remains a bad practice not to use BindingResult in the the method?

Comment: It isn't but you need to take care of the error flow yourself then.